# Weird fonts in google chrome and internet explorer

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

Below a screenshot of stackoverflow.com in google chrome version 42 on my windows 8.1 computer. As you can see the font is not displayed correctly. This also occurs on Internet Explorer version 11. Most websites look ok and this weird font issue only occurs on some website. Firefox and Safari display all websites correctly.

I tried to find a solution for this but i cannot find any information on this particular issue. Any thoughts on what might cause this issue and how to solve it would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]