# Occasional odd fonts in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

On some, but not all websites in Chrome, the font essentially appears as Impact (see screenshot)? Whereas on some websites, the fonts remain as usual. Any suggestions as to why this could be the case?

Note: Just found this thread ([Weird fonts in google chrome and internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782289/weird-fonts-in-google-chrome-and-internet-explorer)) which has the exact same issue but no responses as such.

I've tried solutions listed in:

- [https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/213978011/strange-font-issue-in-chrome?hl=en#:~:text=Try%20a%20quick%20browser%20reset,extension%20is%20causing%20the%20issue.&text=If%20that%20fixes%20the%20issue,know%20which%20extension%20caused%20it.&text=Selecting%20a%20different%20font%20doesn't%20help%3F&text=Try%20Chrome%20beta](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/213978011/strange-font-issue-in-chrome?hl=en#:%7E:text=Try%20a%20quick%20browser%20reset,extension%20is%20causing%20the%20issue.&text=If%20that%20fixes%20the%20issue,know%20which%20extension%20caused%20it.&text=Selecting%20a%20different%20font%20doesn%27t%20help%3F&text=Try%20Chrome%20beta).
- [Why do fonts appear jagged in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535842/why-do-fonts-appear-jagged-in-chrome)

Which hasn't fixed my issues.